How to keep Navbar open after pressing button using HTML/CSS?
I am building a navbar after clicking on a hamburger menu which will take the full screen , and inside the navbar there are many links. Focusing on the button will open the navbar but when I press somewhere on the navbar it will close again because of the button:focus.
I tried to use button:focus to transform the navbar on the screen but it seems that the focus will still be triggered after opening the navbar. All I want is after pressing the button the navbar will be seen and I can press many times on it and it wont disappear.



.openednavbar {
  /* Make full screen */
  position: fixed;
  /*COMBINE WITH TRANSFORM TO KEEP OUT OF PAGE AND ADD SLIDE EFFECT UNLIKE DISPLAY NONE*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #111111, #222222, #333333, #444444 90%);
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.buttonmenu {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonmenu:focus+.openednavbar {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
<button
  class="buttonmenu"
  type="button"
  id="buttonmenu"
  onclick="openNavbar()"
>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24"
    height="24"
    fill="none"
    stroke="white"
    stroke-width="2"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke-linejoin="round"
    class="hamburgermenu"
  >
    <path d="M3 12h18M3 6h18M3 18h18"></path>
  </svg>
</button>

<!-- OPEN NAV BAR -->
<div class="openednavbar" id="openednavbar"></div>




Please visit [ask], then click [edit] and then the [<>] button and make a [mcve]

I made you the snippet. Now please edit it and add relevant HTML and JS (if needed) plus frameworks from CDN

you want me to add my full code @mplungjan

RELEVANT code in a [mcve]
